# 12.04 Issues - Missing drop down menu / missing evolution / no shut down and missing navigation bar

Tags: 12.04

Not a unix expert, running ubuntu on an older acer 5315 laptop as was better than vista.
upgrade to 12.04 was interrupted, frozen at battery state. Solved this with alt f5 and sudo get apt something or other and can get ubuntu login screen. starts ubuntu with only 4 folders on the left, no slide out menu, nothing but calendar top right. if i run sudo unity -- reset I get the slide out menu and a load of errors. need somehow to fix this so it works but more importantly get evolution back - wife has masses of emails and folders so cant risk an install that will lose this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not a unix expert but experienced similar difficulties.

Once I managed to get to the desktop and open a terminal I followed this [manual upgrade guide](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/10/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-from-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-via-the-console-server/).

In case that site gets removed, the key procedure for me was:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I then restarted my machine, logged in and opened the "Update Manager". This displayed >300 updates which I duly installed. Another restart ( sudo shutdown -r now ) or two and the upgrade to 12.04 was complete.